# unit test of method of class with mocking data in python

Tags: python

I have some class SomeClass in file prog.py

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.data_dict = {}

   def load(self):
    """
    """
    if not os.path.exists(self.file_name):
        return False
    with open(self.file_name, "r", encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
        skip_lines(4, file)
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for line in reader:
            if line['Region'] == "":#to remove Copiright and disclaimer text at the end
                break
            
            label=re.sub('\s+/\s+',"/",line['Region']) #remove spaces around /
            if label in self.data_dict.keys():
            #if line['Region'] in self.data_dict.keys():
                self.data_dict[label][line['Range']] = int(line['All people'])
                #self.data_dict[line['Region']][line['Range']] = line['All people']
            else:
                self.data_dict[label] = {line['Range']:int(line['All people'])}
                #self.data_dict[line['Region']] = {line['Range']:line['All people']}
    return True

          
    def regions(self):
        return list(self.data_dict.keys())
```

I need to:

- Create a file named test_someclass_data.py.
- Use import to import the prog module.
- In the test_someclass_data.py file, create a unit test class named
  TestSomeClass that inherits from unittest.TestCase.
- The unit test class should include member functions to test the
  regions member function of the SomeClass class.

My code of test_someclass_data.py:

```
import unittest
import prog

class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_regions(self):
        """
        Test regions function of the SomeClass class.
        
        """
        prog.SomeClass.data_dict ={"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
        test_output = prog.SomeClass.regions()
        expected_output =["key1", "key2"]
        self.assertEqual(test_output, expected_output)
```

I need to test a function of the SomeClass, so I have to create an instance of the class, call method call to store data, then I can compare outputs.  Could you advise me, please, how to avoid this and test functions through mocking? Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code that needs to be mocked and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You have to create an instance of `SomeClass` to use its methods.

Comment: @KlausD. I need to test the method regions() of SomeClass class. Its code is:  def regions(self):
        return list(self.data_dict.keys())

Comment: @zvone I can create instance of the class SomeClass, but its constructor includes filename of file to read. If I create instance of the class with the same file, it will return same list of regions. Or you advice to create with a new file? Could you clarify, please, how it might look like?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, but if you don't want to load from the file, you can mock the `load` method, so that it does not actually load from a file.

Comment: @zvone I have added code into load(). The problem is that I can create an instance of class only with some file and load data from the file, if I use my current file, it seems that the test doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Not sure this needs to be a class. Presumably, you load the file once and retrieve the regions once. A pair of regular functions, one for each task, probably makes more sense. Further, testing is easier if you make the caller of the `load` function responsible for opening an existing file and passing the file-like object to `load`; then `load` can take an arbitrary file-like object, not just an actual file.

Comment: @chepner It is a part of the task: "The unit test class should include member functions to test the regions member function of the SomeClass class".

Comment: Just pointing out this is a poorly written assignment, one that's not really indicative of good code. It reads more like some one with a Java/C++ background and not much Python experience would write.

Comment: @chepner unfortunately, I have to solve the problem in python regardless quality of the code.

Comment: The way you split how much is done in `load` and how much is done in `regions` is up to you. If the goal of the assignment is to mock `load` and test `regions`, I would say more logic should be in `regions`, whereas `load` could e.g. just read the contents of the file and return them.